# how to apply autojs master or jquery.asuggest in summernote editor or ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, autosuggest, summernote

Note that its working fine on input  type "text" or "textarea" but when applying on summernote editor/ck editor its won't working

please flow that link actually i need this in my summernote editor or ckeditor

[http://imankulov.github.io/asuggest/][1]  **OR** [http://atmb4u.github.io/AutoJS/][2]

**my js code is :**

function showTemplateFrom(){

```
var ajaxURL = "getTemplateFromOtNote.do";   
$.ajax({    
    url : ajaxURL,
    success : function(result) {
        $("#dashbordDataDiv").html(result);
    },  complete:function (){

        $('.summernote').summernote({
              height: 300,                 // set editor height
              minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
              maxHeight: null

            });

        $('.modal.aside').ace_aside();

        // asuggest
        var suggests = ["hello", "world" , "doctor" , "document"];
        $("#otTemplateValue").asuggest(suggests);

       //For Ckeditor

        var oTextbox = new AutoSuggestControl("text-area");
    }
});
```

}

**my html code is :**

```
            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <label for="">OT Note Editor</label>
                <div class="summernote" id="otTemplateValue" style="z-index: -99999"></div>

   <p><textarea id="text-area" class="ckeditor" rows="2" cols="50"> </textare></p>


            </div>
```

Comment: Salaam Shamin. It could be related to the fact that summernote has autocorrect built in.

Comment: alaikum as salaam @norcal johnny, do you please provide me summernote autocorrect API name or Link

Answer (score 1):

I believe this method should work on any input field. The key being

`spellcheck="true"` and `spellcheck="false"`

and for autosuggest.

`autocomplete="off"` and `autocomplete="on"`

```html
<!-- spellcheck everything! -->
<input type="text" spellcheck="true" autocomplete="on"/><br />
<textarea spellcheck="true"></textarea>
<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">I am some content</div>

<!-- spellcheck nothing! -->
<input type="text" spellcheck="false" /><br />
<textarea spellcheck="false"></textarea>
<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">I am some content</div>
```

**Keep in mind that these features can be turned off or on within a user's browser settings or 3rd party apps they chose. So nothing is 100% forcible on a visitor.**

Comment: dear, @norcal johnny my requirement is autosuggest like you writeValue "doc" the system suggest you "doctar" or "document" for writing faster

Comment: please flow that link actually i need this in my summernote editor thanks    http://imankulov.github.io/asuggest/

Comment: Did you see this part? This plugin is deprecated..this is over 6 years old sadly.

Comment: ya i know that, but i did not find any better updated lib file like asuggest.. actually i have no option for my requirement.